# Cloning rows not cloning tr

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to cloning table `row`. But i'm only able cloning what inside it without the `tr` tag. Please check my script

```js
$(".tr_clone_add").on('click', function() {
  $('.tr_clone').last().clone({
    withDataAndEvents: true
  }).insertBefore('.tr_clone_add:first');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Hari</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>


  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td>
        <select id="dropdown" class="form-control" name="hari[]">
          <option>Senin</option>
          <option>Selasa</option>
          <option>Rabu</option>
          <option>Kamis</option>
          <option>Jumat</option>
        </select>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" name="add" value="Tambah Baris" class="tr_clone_add">
```

How can i fix it? Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: The problem is you are not appending it to the table, tr_clone_add is the button.... `.insertBefore('.tr_clone:first');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that `clone()` accepts a boolean value as the first parameter, not an object.

Secondly your issue is because you're appending the `tr` element before the button, not inside the table. Instead, try using `appendTo('table tbody')` like this:

```js
$(".tr_clone_add").on('click', function() {
  $('.tr_clone').last().clone(true).appendTo('table tbody');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Hari</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
      <td>
        <select id="dropdown" class="form-control" name="hari[]">
          <option>Senin</option>
          <option>Selasa</option>
          <option>Rabu</option>
          <option>Kamis</option>
          <option>Jumat</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" name="add" value="Tambah Baris" class="tr_clone_add">
```